# Is there a way to place error popups from vscode not upside?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: VS Code error pop up]

Is there a way to place this pop up from VS Code, down below the error or change transparency to 0.75?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your `settings.json`:

```
  "editor.hover.above": false,
```

[image]

Comment: Thansk, solved! 